# How to reuse the part of query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have Java method which call Native SQL (Oracle) via Hibernate:

```
public List<Location> getLocationsAround(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, long retailerId) {
    List<Location> locationList = (List<Location>) SessionManager.getSession().createSQLQuery(
        "SELECT loc.*, distance(ci.coord1, ci.coord2, :latitude, :longitude) as dist " +
        "FROM location loc " +
        "join rl_retailer_location rrl on rrl.location_id = loc.location_id " +
        "join contact_info ci on ci.contact_info_id=loc.contact_info_id " +
        "WHERE rrl.retailer_id=:retailerId " +
        "and NVL(distance(ci.coord1, ci.coord2, :latitude, :longitude), :limit) <= :radius " + 
        "ORDER BY dist ASC"
    ).addEntity("loc", DAO.getInstance().getMappedClass(Location.class))
    .setLong("retailerId", retailerId)
    .setDouble("latitude", latitude)
    .setDouble("longitude", longitude)
    .setDouble("radius", radius)
    .setDouble("limit", radius + 1.)
    .list();
    return locationList;
}
```

For `dist` calculation is used FUNCTION (stored procedure) `distance` which has 4 parameters (numbers): latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2 and returns NUMBER(18,6) or null (if parameter invalid). `dist` is used in ORDER BY for result set sorting.

This version works as expected.

**Question**: How can I rewrite query for reuse part `dist` in WHERE?

**Goal**: eliminate 2x calculation `distance(ci.coord1, ci.coord2, :latitude, :longitude)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle you can use a query as table in your `FROM` clause, so you can do something like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT loc.*
         , distance(ci.coord1, ci.coord2, :latitude, :longitude) as dist
      FROM location loc
      JOIN rl_retailer_location rrl on rrl.location_id = loc.location_id
      JOIN contact_info ci on ci.contact_info_id=loc.contact_info_id
     WHERE rrl.retailer_id=:retailerId
     ) loc
 WHERE dist <= :radius
 ORDER BY dist ASC
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you @Sergio. I only changed WHERE clause to `WHERE NVL(dist, :over) <= :radius`.